# How to parse a given key-value parameters string?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string:

> Parameter1="Something related to this" Parameter2="Another value" Parameter3='Single quotes are permitted' Parameter4="Even HTML entities are permitted"

I want to get this list:

1. Parameter1=Something related to this
2. Parameter2=Another value
3. Parameter3=Single quotes are permitted
4. Parameter4=Even HTML entities are permitted

I tried this regex. But it's not working:

```
(\w+)=(('|"|&quot;)).*(('|"|&quot;))
```

How can I parse this string and extract key-value pairs?

Comment: `(\w+)=(['"]|&quot;)(.*?)\2`, see https://regex101.com/r/rjIBB2/1

Comment: Seems that it's not getting the `&quote;` in C#. I tested in RegexHero.

Comment: There is no `&quote;` entity, there is only `&quot;`. You have a typo in the sample string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```cs
(\w+)=(['"]|&quot;)(.*?)\2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rjIBB2/1). *Details*:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `=` - an equals sign
- `(['"]|&quot;)` - Group 2: `'`, `"` or `&quot;`
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than an LF char as few as possible
- `\2` - Group 2 value.